# Group by with percentages and raw numbers

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image: six columns: area (categorical), amount ($), population (categorical), purpose (categorical), purpose2(categorical), county(categorical)]

I would like to create a table that groups by area and shows the total amount for the area both as a percentage of total amount and as a raw number, as well as the percent of the total number of records/observations per area and total number of records/observations as a raw number.

The code below works to generate a table of raw numbers but does not the show percent of total:

```
tabstat amount, by(county) stat(sum count)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide us with a [mcve] using Stata's `dataex` command. Pictures are not useful in helping us providing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a canned command for doing what you want. You will have to program the table yourself.

Here's a quick example using `auto.dta`:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. tabstat price, by(foreign) stat(sum count)

Summary for variables: price
     by categories of: foreign (Car type)

 foreign |       sum         N
---------+--------------------
Domestic |    315766        52
 Foreign |    140463        22
---------+--------------------
   Total |    456229        74
------------------------------
```

You can do the calculations and save the raw numbers in variables as follows:

```
. generate total_obs = _N

. display total_obs
74

. count if foreign == 0
  52

. generate total_domestic_obs = r(N)

. count if foreign == 1
  22

. generate total_foreign_obs = r(N)

. egen total_domestic_price = total(price) if foreign == 0 

. sort total_domestic_price
. local tdp = total_domestic_price

. display total_domestic_price
315766

. egen total_foreign_price = total(price)  if foreign == 1

. sort total_foreign_price
. local tfp = total_foreign_price

. display total_foreign_price
140463

. generate total_price = `tdp' + `tfp' 

. display total_price
456229
```

And for the percentages:

```
. generate pct_domestic_price = (`tdp' / total_price) * 100

. display pct_domestic_price
69.212173

. generate pct_foreign_price = (`tfp' / total_price) * 100 

. display pct_foreign_price 
30.787828
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a more automated way to do the above without having to specify individual values:

```
program define foo

syntax varlist(min=1 max=1), by(string)

generate total_obs = _N
display total_obs

quietly levelsof `by', local(nlevels)

foreach x of local nlevels {
    count if `by' == `x'
    quietly generate total_`by'`x'_obs = r(N)

    quietly egen total_`by'`x'_`varlist' = total(`varlist') if `by' == `x' 
    sort total_`by'`x'_`varlist'
    local tvar`x' = total_`by'`x'_`varlist'
    local tvarall `tvarall' `tvar`x'' +
    display total_`by'`x'_`varlist'
}

quietly generate total_`varlist' = `tvarall' 0 
display total_`varlist'

foreach x of local nlevels {
    quietly generate pct_`by'`x'_`varlist' = (`tvar`x'' / total_`varlist') * 100
    display pct_`by'`x'_`varlist'
}

end
```

The results are identical:

```
. foo price, by(foreign)
74
  52
315766
  22
140463
456229
69.212173
30.787828
```

You will obviously need to format the results in a table of your liking.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this example is a bit different than what I'm looking for, I don't want to have to specify the different area values

Comment: What you want and what you can get out-of-the-box in Stata are two completely different things. As i said in my answer, you can only get what you want by creating a custom program that does all this and which you can invoke in a single line. Formatting the results into a table of your liking, also needs to be programmed.

Comment: @AshleyBrown See my edit for an example of such a program. this can be further improved of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. I stole @Pearly Spencer's example. It could be generalised to a command. The main message I want to convey is that `list` is useful for tabulations and other reports, with just usually some obligation to calculate what you want to show beforehand.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. preserve 

. collapse (sum) total=price (count) obs=price, by(foreign)

. egen pc2 = pc(total)

. egen pc1 = pc(obs)

. char pc2[varname]  "%"

. char pc1[varname]  "%"

. format pc* %2.1f 

. list foreign obs pc1 total pc2 , subvarname noobs sum(obs pc1 total pc2) 

      +-----------------------------------------+
      |  foreign   obs       %    total       % |
      |-----------------------------------------|
      | Domestic    52    70.3   315766    69.2 |
      |  Foreign    22    29.7   140463    30.8 |
      |-----------------------------------------|
  Sum |             74   100.0   456229   100.0 |
      +-----------------------------------------+


. restore
```

EDIT Here's an essay in `egen` with similar  flavour but leaving the original data in place and new variables also available for export or graphics.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. egen total = sum(price), by(foreign) 

. egen obs = count(price), by(total) 

. egen tag = tag(foreign) 

. egen pc2 = pc(total) if tag
(72 missing values generated)

. egen pc1 = pc(obs) if tag 
(72 missing values generated)

. char pc2[varname]  "%"

. char pc1[varname]  "%"

. format pc* %2.1f 

. list foreign obs pc1 total pc2 if tag, subvarname noobs sum(obs pc1 total pc2) 

      +-----------------------------------------+
      |  foreign   obs       %    total       % |
      |-----------------------------------------|
      | Domestic    52    70.3   315766    69.2 |
      |  Foreign    22    29.7   140463    30.8 |
      |-----------------------------------------|
  Sum |             74   100.0   456229   100.0 |
      +-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `collapse` is the first thing that comes to mind for such calculations but what i have always really disliked about it is that it destroys the current dataset. I agree that `list` can be quite handy but if the table is a bit more complex you need to create it yourself. As a suggestion, you may want to edit your answer to include a `save` / `merge` so the generated data are included in the main dataset.

Comment: Producing a reduced dataset is the main purpose of `collapse`,  so there you go: my code deliberately includes `preserve` and `restore` as a hint. I happily flag your suggestion to the OP: this is a forum for professional and enthusiastic programmers, after all.

Comment: @PearlySpencer I thought of another approach avoiding `collapse`.